# AngularJS2 component not loading after adding router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

AngularJS2 app component is not loading after adding the router. There is no error in the log. if I remove the router it starts working again. Does anyone faced this kind of issue before. I am using 'lite-server' to run the application.

angular js version : "2.4.0",

router version : "~3.4.8",

lite-server version: "^2.2.2",

**This is how I add router to my app.**

step 1: added '`<base href="/">`' to index.html

step 2: added router links to my component.html

```
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/new">Contacts</a> 
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

step 3: my router.ts looks like below

```
export const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: ContactListComponent },
      { path: '/new', component: NewContactComponent },
      { path: '/about', component: AboutComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]  
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

step 4: added routing component to the module like below

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactListComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    NewContactComponent,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [ContactService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Also tried to inject router like below

```
export class AppComponent {

   constructor(private routes: Router) { 

   }

}
```

So can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with no slash (/) :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: ContactListComponent },
      { path: 'new', component: NewContactComponent },
      { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent }
];
```

With slashes you'll probably get an error ("path cannot start with a slash...").

Comment: excellent it worked, I was totally stuck. thanks for the reply